# how can i view the data resulting from one of the choices in the dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql

im new to php so im having some problems creating what i want

i'll explain first what i need .. there conferences, each conference has a list of reviewers and authors.

i have create a dropdown list where the user chooses which conference ... i want to show a list of the reviewers and the authors that are in this conference after clicking submit.

that is my code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
mysql_select_db("messaging_dd", $con);
$sql_drop = "SELECT conference_ID,conference_name FROM Conferences";
$drop_result = mysql_query($sql_drop,$con) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($drop_result) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
?>

<form name="choose" action="savedata.php" method="POST">
    <br />
    Conference: <select name="conference">
        <?php
        for($i=0 ; $i<$num_rows ; $i++)
        {
            $idofconference = mysql_result($drop_result,$i,0);
            $nameofconference = mysql_result($drop_result,$i,1);
            echo '<option value=" '.$idofconference.' ">'.$nameofconference.'</option>';
        }
        ?>        
    </select> 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: where is reviewers and authors ?? is that in conference table ?? or in different table ??

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$conf_id = $_POST['conference'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
mysql_select_db("messaging_dd", $con);
$sql = "SELECT review, author FROM Reviews WHERE conf_id = ".$conf_id;
$review_list = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
```

Or you can go for Ajax. Updating your search result, without reloading the whole page. Reference for Ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 1):

All the data being submitted gets stored in the [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable as an array. Your conference ID will be in `$_POST['conference']` as the name of your select element is `conference`.

An other approach is to load the desired data (reviewers and authors) through an [AJAX request](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/a/aa101705.htm) so that the viewer of your website won't leave the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

it's similar to what you have done, just add conference id details like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT reviewer, author FROM Conferences where conference_ID = " . $_POST['conference'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file `savedata.php` you can put

```
$whatever = $_POST['conference']
```

`$_POST` is one of several arrays in php that is reserved for system data, for example you can make calls to $_server to find out details about the server(eg the time on the server)

you could also change the method='POST' to method='GET' and it would be in the GET array

```
$whatever = $_GET['conference']
```

this is a bit less secure, but if that's not a priority its worth considering

Answer (score 1):

I think you should Try this.

```
<form name="choose" action="savedata.php" method="POST">
    <br />
    Conference: <select name="conference">
        <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($drop_result)
        {
            echo '<option value=" '.$idofconference.' ">'.$nameofconference.'</option>';

        }
        ?>        
    </select>
```